# CUDA install causing login loop

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, lightdm, cuda

I have configured & installed CUDA twice already, both from completely fresh installs of 14.04.3 LTS (worth noting the machine dual-boots Windows 10 [separate drives though]). Both times, after a couple days of running fine it will get me stuck in a login loop. I tried `chown username:username` on the `.Xauthority`, modifying `/tmp`, reconfiguring `lightdm` ([From Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)). However, nothing seems to work.

For reference I installed *both* the nVidia driver and CUDA via runfile method. I will update with the distros after I reboot into my linux box to check.

> NVIDIA Linux 64bit 352.41
>
> CUDA 7.5

Comment: Any updates? I hope this doesn't happen to me, as I also have 14.04 and 7.5. Anyways, I choose the *deb (network) install, as updating the *run install is designed to be a pain. I don't think it's supposed to work with updated kernels, and it doesn't.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, and have also tried the same remedies. The deb network install also fails for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that installing the cuda driver without opengl helps, provided you only want the GPU for compute. This is done by adding either --no-opengl-libs (or --no-opengl-files) during the run file install.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same problem. So I switch to TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and created a new user and found out that I can login using the new user. Then I realize that if I use the new user's `$HOME/.profile`, I can login too. Finally, the problem lies in the `$HOME/.profile`, the troublesome line is:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\*/cuda\*:\*/nvidia\*:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It turns out that if your current graphics card is not compatible with the Nvidia driver or CUDA library, desktop login will crash the X session. It seems like a bug in the gnome-session.

Your case might be different though.

My problem is solved now -:)